# How to check that data (1.5m+ rows) were extracted correctly from a .txt file

Tags: r, dataframe

8 variables were extracted from a .txt file, the following image is an example of the raw data:

"lat", "lon", "elev", "var"(the long string in the third row), "year", "mth", "day" and "data" (value):

[image]

An .Rdata file was created with 1.5M+ rows. The following image is a screenshot of the results:

[image]

As you can see, these rows seem to be correctly extracted from the .txt file and I have manually checked the first 1,000 rows but I cannot do this for the rest of the file.

**My question is:** how can I efficiently check that the 1.5 m rows are correctly extracted?

Comment: by "extracted", do you mean read into R using `read.table` or `read.csv` ? Based on that I can give you a list of things you could do to verify your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @hedgedandlevered 's answer and @vagabond 's comment there are a number of things you can do, probably systematically, to check your data frame prior to analysis. I looked around Stack Overflow but couldn't find a question about checking a dataframe, so for what it's worth this is the procedure I use when I load in a file.

I use `dplyr` and convert my data frame to a `dbf_tbl` so that output is sensible. Using the built in data set `iris`:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
require("dplyr")
iris <- tbl_df(iris)
iris
```

This shows the head of the file and which variables haven't been printed (if any). This shows me if there are any obvious problems, such as the data frame not loading correctly. I don't bother with `tail()` but it can't hurt.

Next I would check I have the correct number of rows (cases) as expected. This is printed by `dplyr` or can be explicitly checked with:

```
nrow(iris)
```

From here it depends on the individual data as to how I proceed, but it's a case of sanity checking as suggested by @hedgedandlevered . In your case I would make sure the latitude and longitude co-ordinates look sensible with:

```
range(df$lat)
range(df$long)
summary(df$lat)
summary(df$long)
```

I'd check specifically for NAs, and I might even plot a random selection of the points in some GIS software (or use R!) to make sure the points look reasonable.

As for year, month, and day I'd do a similar summary/range to make sure the values were sensible:

```
range(df$year)  # only you can know what values are sensible
range(df$month)  # hopefully 1 - 12 only!
range(df$day)  # you get the idea...
```

Finally, make sure `$data` looks reasonable with `summary()` and maybe even a boxplot:

```
boxplot(df$data)
```

If you have data (i.e. a data frame with numbers in it, rather than NAs or 0s) you can assume that the data has been loaded correctly. I have never experienced a situation where R 'makes stuff up', so if there's stuff there, it's correct. Having said that, if you have situations where you have too many NAs, you can look for them with:

```
which(is.na(df$data))
```

Which will print the index/indices of offending row numbers for you to explore further by subsetting:

For example, if you have a variable with NAs in rows 1, 2, and 3, you can look at just these rows with:

```
subset <- which(is.na(df$variable))
View(df[subset, ])
```

Addition: RStudio from v0.99.x now includes a more sophisticated data view, so you can open you date with `View(df)` (note capital 'V') and explore, subset, and filter the dataset more easily through the GUI.

Checking and verifying data frames isn't trivial and can't easily be automated, but there are tools out there to help you make it more efficient. They don't say cleaning and checking data takes more time than the analysis for nothing, though!

Answer (score 0):

What properties should the table have? should "year" only be within certain bounds? should the index be always-increasing? Should there always be a constant number of measurements for each longitude measure? 
Coming up with a few sanity checks should be sufficient; if the rows seem right for a while, and they pass the sanity checks, you're probably good to go with enough certainty

example:

`unique(df[,'year'])`

Alternatively, you could write the table to the same format that you read it from, then compare the MD5s (google for MD5 help)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Precisely what I was looking for.